# Webmethod in aspx codebehind not being hit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I have a `WebMethod` in the code behind which is not being hit. I've googled a lot and found lots of questions like this. I've tried all suggestions I've seen whit no success.

IDE: Visual Studio 2017
Framework: 4.0
jQuery version: 3.1.1
Project type: Webforms (yeah, I miss my beloved MVC but it's not my fault!)

The error:

> {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027id\u0027.","StackTrace":"    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

URL being called: GET http://localhost:65050/Default.aspx/Save?{"id":"chkEditable","wasChecked":"on"}

When I click on any of the two check boxes, I get the following error on Chrome console

> GET
>   http://localhost:65050/Default.aspx/Save?{%22id%22:%22chkEditable%22,%22wasChecked%22:%22on%22}
>   500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4

Here's my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="TesteWebMethod.Default" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chkVisible').change(function () {
            Save('chkVisible', $('#chkVisible').val());
        });

        $('#chkEditable').change(function () {
            Save('chkEditable', $('#chkEditable').val());
        });
    });

    function Save(_id, _state) {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>';
        var _data = { "id": _id, "wasChecked": _state };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pageUrl + "/Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(_data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: OnFailure
        });
    }

    function OnFailure(response) {
        console.log('falha');
        alert(response.d);
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log('sucesso');
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ID="chkVisible" Text="Visivel" />
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ID="chkEditable" Text="Editavel" />
</form>
```

And here is the code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TesteWebMethod
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod(true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Save(string id, string wasChecked)
    {
        bool b = wasChecked == "on";

        string data = "Id " + (b ? "was checked" : "was unchecked");

        JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var json = TheSerializer.Serialize(data);

        return json;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

I really got stuck on this. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be that the method you are calling is a GET method, but you are passing data as if the method were a POST method. Webforms will not take parameters out of the request content and act like they came from the query string.  That JSON data you are including in the request needs to be URL encoded into the query string, or the method needs to be converted into a POST method as well as the AJAX call.

Comment: Even if the JSON data is making it into a query string, I don't believe that the method will correctly parse it into the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Hist. I think I did do many changes on the code trying to make it work that at certain point I became lost. I've just change from GET to POST and it worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't stringify your `json` object if you set your object to the `data` property jquery will know how to build a `GET` request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pageUrl + "/Save",
    data: {"id": _data.id, "wasChecked": "'" + _data.wasChecked + "'"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: OnFailure
});
```

Notice that I had to curate the data adding single quotes to the wasChecked attribute because [That's the way ASP knows that's a string](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs#L408), which I think it's a terrible implementation.

As Kevin said, a POST would be much better. It would

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebMethodTest.aspx/Save",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 2, "wasChecked": "test" }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

And

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Save(string id, string wasChecked)
{
```

Comment: As Kevin suggested, I changed to POST and removed _UseHttpGet = true_ parameter on annotation and it worked. Thanks @kblok,